# Reference Request for a theorem in Sturm-Liouville theory

Tags: reference-request, sturm-liouville

I have read that the eigenfunctions of a Sturm-Liouville operator form an orthonormal basis, can someone give me a reference to the proof of this proposition? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link:

[https://www.amazon.com/Sturm-Liouville-Theory-Anton-Zettl/dp/0821852671/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=sturm-liouville+theory&qid=1619756533&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821852671)

This is a well-regarded text on the subject of Sturm-Liouville Theory.